# Junit Job getting Stuck after migrating to Jenkins 2.19.1

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I recently moved to Jenkins 2.19.1 and imported all my jobs from older version to this version of jenkins.
After moving to the new Jenkins my Junit job is getting stuck very frequently.

> JUNIT Plugin version 1.19

If I abort the job and start again it runs properly. But again after couple of days or after 6-7 job executions get stuck again.
It does not throw any error and I cannot see anythings in the logs.
The job gets stuck for infinite time, I have waited for more then 26hrs but it does not move a bit.
It get stuck at the same place.

```
18:22:16     [junit] JMockit: No classes were instrumented for coverage; please make sure that classes selected for coverage have been compiled with debug information.
18:22:18     [junit] JMockit: loaded external tool mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage
18:22:19     [junit] JMockit: No classes were instrumented for coverage; please make sure that classes selected for coverage have been compiled with debug information.
18:22:21     [junit] JMockit: loaded external tool mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage
```

I dont think there is a issue with code or test cases, else it should not re-execute.
Can somebody help me to know the exact issue.

Comment: Can you upgrade the Junit plugin to 1.20 and let us know if the problem persists?

Comment: Does this happen only with one specific job or with multiple different ones?

Comment: I think the problem was with the box we were hosting.. Once migrated to another box, I had not faced this issue.